# ViewBox automatically change postion of my control

Tags: wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2012

I am writing an application using WPF in visual studio 2012.
I want to use Viewbox control to solve problem of resizing application. Now when I try to place other controls in Viewbox, I see that I can't change the position of controls. It seems that Viewbox change automatically the positions of controls!

Picture(1) is result
and picture(2) is what I want.

[image: Result]

picture(1)

[image: Desired]

picture(2)

Please help me.

Comment: Hi, it would help to see an example (`wpf`) of the problem you're having, and what your desired result is. Are you trying to drag and drop items from the designer on into a `ViewBox`?

Comment: Explain it better what is the expected and the experienced behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify how you want the `ViewBox` to align the child element it's stretching.

```
<Viewbox VerticalAlignment="Top">
```

Should place your elements at your desired location.

You can also specify how the `ViewBox` will `Stretch` it's content, and the `HorizontalAlignment`, if required.

Additionaly, you can specify `StretchDirection="UpOnly"`, to ensure that your controls are never scaled below the initial size you specify.

Comment: Thank you Chris. Is it possible to set control locations manually using only designer?

Comment: Hi, it is possible, but your results will depend on what you're doing with your layout and `Viewbox`. I find it makes sense to finalise your control layout first, and apply the `Viewbox` afterwards, you may find it tricky to design whilst a `Viewbox` is active.